# Multiple attributes on HTML elements using ArcGIS API

Tags: html, arcgis

I use ArcGIS API JavaScript to get values from a REST service into a table.

The main ID needs to be in 1st `<th>` field, but the value names are sometimes different.

I have this:

```
<th field="NR">Nummer</th>
```

But NR attribute value could also be NUMMER,

If I use instead:

```
<th field="NR">Nummer</th>
<th field="NUMMER">Nummer</th>
```

I always get a `NULL` field and I don't want that..

Is there a way to assign multiple attribute values to a `<th>` element.

**like this?**

```
if (strUser==="Sporen"){

    findTask = new esri.tasks.FindTask("https://gis.strukton.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/ProRail_Data/MapServer");
     var findParams = new esri.tasks.FindParameters();
    findParams.returnGeometry = true;
    findParams.layerIds = [31];
    findParams.searchFields = ["NR"];
var field1 = $('.selected').data('field1');

    findParams.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;


    findParams.searchText = dojo.byId("ownerName").value;
    findTask.execute(findParams,showResults);
```

}

Comment: I can see that English is not native language but you will have to define your question much more clearly in order for us to know what you're after...

Comment: I use arcgis javascript API i use a find and identify fro this sample code http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm#jssamples/mobile_findnearby.html. In the sample, they use only one FindTask, i need multiple find Tasks..

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend doing it the html5 way. I'd be like this:

```
<th data-field1="NR" data-field2="NUMMBER" class="selected">Nummer</th>
```

Then in jquery you could access either this way:

```
$('.selected').data('field1');
$('.selected').data('field2');
```

or if you don't want field2 in there and you just want to get the text you can do:

```
<th data-field1="NR" class="selected">Nummer</th>
var field1 = $('.selected').data('field1');
var field2 = $('.selected').text();
```

Comment: Could you do a little explanation here? im not sure how you do it. And where i need to put "NR" and "NUMMER"

Comment: what I'm saying is you can have any attribute on the th as long as it has data- in front of it and then you need an id or class so you could access it. I will update my example to show where they'd go.

Comment: Like this:
if (strUser==="bovenleidingpaal"){
    findTask = new esri.tasks.FindTask("https://gis.strukton.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/ProRail_Data/MapServer");
         var findParams = new esri.tasks.FindParameters();
        findParams.returnGeometry = true;
        findParams.layerIds = [26];
        findParams.searchFields = ["NUMMER"];
$('.selected').data('field2');

        findParams.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;
  
  
  findParams.searchText = dojo.byId("ownerName").value;
  findTask.execute(findParams,showResults);
   }

Comment: please update your question instead of putting it in the comment. It's very hard to understand all on one line, but from your example you aren't setting the data to a variable you can use. I've updated my example to have the data set to a variable that you can then use in your javascript. Also make sure jquery is included.

Comment: I included it like this:         <link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/redmond/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" /> And put the example in a update

Answer (score 1):

Using arcgis it looks like you can just change line:

```
findParams.searchFields = ["NR"];
```

to

```
findParams.searchFields = ["NR","NUMMER"];
```

Comment: No, in different MapServers the main ID = NR, or NUMMER. These values are not in every MapServer..
And the problem lies at the <th> side